# How to check whether data stored in a text file meets specific criteria?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file with this info stored in it

```
01
```

I made a simple code that should interpret the numbers but it does not work

```
 with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
 if data[0] == '00':
    name = 'test0'
 if data[0] == '01':
    name = 'test1'
 if data[0] == '02':
    name = 'test2'
 else:
    name = 'ERROR'
 print(name)
```

Any time I run this code it prints ERROR but if I print data[0] it prints 01.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Invisible control characters? What does `print(repr(data[0]))` print?

Comment: The value would contain a newline, wouldn't it?

Comment: try adding data[0].lstrip() to make sure there are no empty spaces when reading the data?

Comment: You need to make 2nd and 3rd if statements elif's, Your if statements are working but they're being over written by your final one checking for "02".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your if statements. This is the correct format that your code should be using:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\edekio\Documents\test.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
    if data[0].strip() == '00':
       name = 'test0'
    elif data[0].strip() == '01':
       name = 'test1'
    elif data[0].strip() == '02':
       name = 'test2'
    else:
       name = 'ERROR'

print(name)
```

Output

```
test1
```

By using multiple if statements, your code will check **ALL** of the cases for a **TRUE** case and executing the code in the following line. So after it does that match in the second if statement, it will check again for the third if statement and see if it is true. Since it is not true, if will execute the else clause.

By using elif and not multiple if statements, your code will execute the line where it returns a **TRUE** statement and not check for other conditional statements.

I added the [strip()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/strip.html) to the lines as good practice. Often times you will not know if there are leading characters which will falsify your condition when searching for exact string matches. [strip()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/strip.html) ensures you never have to worry about it.

Comment: Odd because I have tested it on my computer with exact results. What python version are you using? And make sure you are reading in the correct path.

Comment: I am using python version 3.7

Comment: And are you using the same indentation that I am using? Your indentation was incorrect in your question.

Comment: Yes I copied your answer directly

Comment: try changing lstrip to strip like in my edited answer now. Runs perfectly on my machine.

Comment: Now I am getting this error message

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lstrip'

Comment: Sorry I wasn't done with that edit before I posted it. That was a previous edit. Use what I have above where i don't modify data directly but each of the data[0] with data[0].strip.

Comment: @nick4356123 Remember to always use strip when reading in data

Answer (score 0):

As with all text, and as mentioned in the comments, it's wise to strip all white-space characters before applying Boolean comparisons. Use `data[0].strip()` to do this.

If you only want to remove it from the left of the string use `data[0].lstrip()` and correspondingly on the right `data[0].rstrip()`.

Comment: This was only half of the issue. The major issue was the use of the if-if-if syntax. He wouldn't need to strip if he typed in 01 correctly into the file.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh Good catch